# Was Devi Sarada an avatar of Goddess Jagadamba/Durga?

Tags: shiva, durga, parvati, kali

Many people had told me that Ramakrishna Paramahamsa's wife Devi Sarada was an avatar of Goddess Jagadamba/Durga. Is this true?

Comment: But then how is it possible because I have heard Ramakrishna Paramahamsa was an incarnation of Lord Vishnu.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is truth that Devi Sarada was a form of Goddess Durga. Sri Ramakrishna Paramhansa had worshipped Devi Sarada because he thought that his mother Kali or Jagadamba had  came in the form of his wife Sarada Devi. I also believe that Devi Sarada was an avatar of Goddess Durga.

Comment: You should cite sources for you answer.